# Retrofit + RxJava - Not emitting when Fragment is restored, if I used Disposable.dispose()

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, rx-java2

I have a `Fragment A` that uses Retrofit to calls an API in `onCreateView`.
The result will be used to display a list of objects.

`Fragment A` also has a button which navigates to `Fragment B`, by commiting a `FragmentTransaction` and replace itself. (`Fragment A` `onDestroyView` triggered)

Everything works well, but when I back from `Fragment B` to `Fragment A`(`Fragment A` `onCreateView` triggered), API is not called.

**This only happens if I call `Disposable.dispose()` in `onDestroyView`**, which is an attempt to prevent memory leaks.

#### What I expect

Since new `Observable`s will be created every time `onCreateView` is triggered, they are supposed to be indenpendent of the previously disposed `Disposables`. And therefore API will be called again and callbacks will be triggered. The list of object should be refreshed.

#### What I observed

`onCreateView` is triggered, the line which tells Retrofit to call API is also triggered. But none of the callbacks (including `.map()`) are triggered. Since I have also logged network traffics, I am pretty sure that no network communication has actually been made. **It looks like either RxJava or Retrofit decided to stop the stream.**

#### The Question

Of course this can be avoided if I do not use `Disposable.dispose()`. But I do want to prevent memory leaks.
What is the correct way to do this?

#### My Code (Simplified)

Fragment A:

```
public class BeansFragment extends BaseFragment {

   ...

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        retrofit.getSomeBeans()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new APIResponseObserver<List<Beans>>(this) {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Beans> beans) {
                        if (getContext() == null) return;
                        setupBeansList(beans);
                    }
                });
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

BaseFragment:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    ...

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        compositeDisposable.dispose();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

Most Importantly, `APIResponseObserver` which does the job of adding the disposable:

```
public abstract class APIResponseObserver<T> implements io.reactivex.Observer<T> {

    private BaseFragment fragment;

    public APIResponseObserver(BaseFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        if (fragment != null) fragment.addToCompositeDisposable(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        //...
    }
}
```

#### Note

I have also tried to use [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle), but produced the same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found out that I should have used `Disposable.clear()` instead of `dispose()`. `dispose()` made me no longer be able to add `Disposable` to the same `CompositeDisposable`.

An interesting fact is, [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle) produces the same problem. Does it mean they use `dispose()` instead of `clear()`?

#### EDIT@2018-04-20

For [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle), you may refer to [this Github issue](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle/issues/131).

Comment: i had the same problem ;) thanks for finding solution